# Mangled physics after moving an object

Tags: physics

I'm trying to do some simple 2D physics. Here's a working version of the animation (I told you it was simple):

https://imgur.com/a/vWdC54K

I now move the rotating green element a bit to the right; I delete the bake; rebake; render.

https://imgur.com/a/gReFX2Y

It's very wrong. (I don't know how to get the movies inlined, sorry. If any helpful editor knows how, feel free to fix...)

This doesn't just happen when rendering, it also happens when doing normal un-baked editing. In fact, it seems to be completely independent of the bake state. What's *really* weird is if I add or remove a ball, everything resets and it's working again.

This sounds as if the physics cache is stale, but in the second video the balls are moving differently to the first, so there's something more going on than just using the old position data for the balls. I have seen references that editing the scene causes the physics cache to be flushed, which explains why everything fixes itself when I add or remove a ball, but surely moving the rotating bar should do the same?

Is there any way to avoid this? Even a way to manually flush the cache (if that's what's needed) would be nice...

(The red balls are rigid body active objects. The green frame is a passive object. The rotating bar is a passive object with animation enabled and a driver on the rotation Y property to make it move. The green way have 1u of depth perpendicular to the camera and the balls themselves are discs with a spherical collider.)

Comment: The first thing I notice is that in the first animation the red balls are touching or at least get very close to the rotating green bar, while in the second animation they are repelled when they are still quite far... did you change the _Collision Margin_ under _Collisions_ > _Sensitivity_? Or maybe you changed the _Shape_ to _Mesh_ or something like that, in this case the _Collision Margin_ checkbox automatically disappears and you just have a _Margin_ value which is 0.04 by default....

Comment: I did check that, and no. It goes from not working to working if I simply select one ball, to Shift+D to duplicate it, place it somewhere, and rerun the animation. I never touch the collision margin setting.